# How can I open an image in the default photos app?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, storage, windows-10, imaging

I have an app that captures images from the device's camera and saves them as `StorageFile`s to a folder in my app's roaming data.  I've been trying to make a page that will open the image and show a preview, but I've been having many problems doing that, so I want to just open the image in the default photos app.  However, I can't find any way to do that.  Using `await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri(@"ms-appdata:///roaming/folder/img.jpg"));` asks if I want to search for an app in the Store (searches for "ms-appdata").  Does the native Photos app for Windows (Phone) have a dedicated URI scheme?  Also, I **am** targeting Windows 10 with this app, so the URI schemes (if any) may have changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Launcher.LaunchUriAsync` is for launching an application using the URI scheme, this is not what you want.

Instead you'll want to launch an app based on a file:
Get the image as a StorageFile

```
var imageFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(@"ms-appdata:///roaming/folder/img.jpg");
```

Then you tell the OS to launch an app to handle that file. It's then up to the user to choose which app to handle the image file:

```
var success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(imageFile);
```

You can read more about "launching" files [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh779671.aspx).